# BigQuery Reddit Comment Data Analysis

Tags: google-bigquery, reddit

BigQuery - Newbie

**Trying to get a pair of users who have both commented on top 10 subreddits and the count of common subreddits on which they have commented using BigQuery Reddit Data**

I have just started with BQ and a beginner at SQL too and I am finding it hard to get this query. Can someone give me some pointers to get started ?

Comment: As Felipe pointed (implicitly) - the best way to start is to present what you've got so far - so we can narrow down our efforts to help you. Otherwise it is too broad and hard to jump in

Answer (score 2):

Never had real needs in playing with reddit data so below is just for throwing at least something for you to start as seems noone is willing.

Quick logic:

```
Step - 1: Identify top 10 most commented subreddits
```

---

```
SELECT subreddit 
FROM [fh-bigquery:reddit_comments.subr_rank_201505] 
ORDER BY comments 
DESC LIMIT 10
```

Step - 2: For each subreddit identify [solid] users (with more than 50 comments)

---

```
SELECT author, subreddit, COUNT(1) AS comments 
FROM [fh-bigquery:reddit_comments.2016_01]  
WHERE subreddit IN (
    SELECT subreddit 
    FROM [fh-bigquery:reddit_comments.subr_rank_201505] 
    ORDER BY comments DESC 
    LIMIT 10)
AND author NOT IN ('AutoModerator', '[deleted]')
GROUP BY author, subreddit 
HAVING comments > 50
```

Step - 3: For each subreddit identify pair of common users (via JOIN) 
Step - 4: And finally, for each pair of users count number of common subreddits

---

```
SELECT usera, userb, COUNT(1) AS subreddits
FROM (
  SELECT 
    a.author AS usera, 
    b.author AS userb, 
    a.subreddit AS subreddit,
  FROM (
    SELECT author, subreddit, COUNT(1) AS comments FROM [fh-bigquery:reddit_comments.2016_01]
    WHERE subreddit IN (SELECT subreddit FROM [fh-bigquery:reddit_comments.subr_rank_201505] ORDER BY comments DESC LIMIT 10)
    AND author NOT IN ('AutoModerator', '[deleted]')
    GROUP BY author, subreddit HAVING comments > 50 ) AS a
  JOIN (
    SELECT author, subreddit, COUNT(1) AS comments FROM [fh-bigquery:reddit_comments.2016_01]
    WHERE subreddit IN (SELECT subreddit FROM [fh-bigquery:reddit_comments.subr_rank_201505] ORDER BY comments DESC LIMIT 10)
    AND author NOT IN ('AutoModerator', '[deleted]')
    GROUP BY author, subreddit HAVING comments > 50 ) AS b
  ON a.subreddit = b.subreddit
  WHERE a.author < b.author 
)
GROUP BY usera, userb
HAVING subreddits > 3
ORDER BY subreddits DESC, usera, userb
```

Hope this helps